# Not unique table/alias: 'quiz_table'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, web-deployment

I've created a web app using code igniter 3 to get data from 3 tables and display them in the view (quiz_table,question_table and answers_table).
Below is the model code,

```
function getSingleQuizQuestionDataFromDB($quizId)
{        //insert query
    try {
        $this->db->select('quiz_table.quizName');
        $this->db->select('quiz_table.creatorName');
        $this->db->select('quiz_table.rating');
        $this->db->select('question_table.questionId');
        $this->db->select('question_table.questionTitle');
        $this->db->select('question_table.correctAnswer');
        $this->db->select('answer_table.answer');
        $this->db->from('quiz_table');
        $this->db->where('quiz_table.quizId',$quizId);
        $this->db->join('question_table','question_table.quizId = quiz_table.quizId','INNER');
        $this->db->join('answer_table','answer_table.questionId= question_table.questionId','INNER');
        $this->db->from('quiz_table');
        $this->db->group_by(['quiz_table.quizId', 'question_table.questionId']);
        $result = $this->db->get();


        $singleQuizQuestionData= $result->result_array();
        return $singleQuizQuestionData;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // log_message('error: ',$e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
}
```

When I try to load the result I get the below error
[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple `from()` clauses are not allowed in Codeigniter. Removing the second `from()` will fix the issue

```
$this->db->from('quiz_table'); <---- here
$this->db->where('quiz_table.quizId',$quizId);
$this->db->join('question_table','question_table.quizId = quiz_table.quizId','INNER');
$this->db->join('answer_table','answer_table.questionId= question_table.questionId','INNER');
$this->db->from('quiz_table');  <---- here
$this->db->group_by(['quiz_table.quizId', 'question_table.questionId']);
```